# How to turn a Postgres result with varying number of results into an ordered list in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I have two tables, one with a list of countries; another with the list of years and values for a given variable.

The second table holds entries for certain years only, which differ for the countries. So that, when I join the tables (to get the name of the countries, not displayed in the following list) a result does look like this:

```
      id_country    year_start  value_ori
        886            2002      161.348
        886            2003      161.348
        886            2004      176.016
        886            2005      176.016
        886            2006      179.683
        886            2007      183.35
        886            2008      201.685
        886            2009      227.354
        886            2010      234.688
        886            2011      245.689
        886            2012      293.36
        886            2013      440.04
        620            1990      40.337
        620            1991      1056.096
        620            1992      1151.438
        620            1993      1389.793
        620            1994      1584.144
        620            1995      1631.815
        620            1996      1749.159
        620            1997      1796.83
        620            1998      1906.84
        620            1999      1664.818
        620            2000      1642.816
        620            2001      2016.85
        620            2002      1760.16
        620            2003      1873.837
        620            2004      1961.845
        620            2005      2310.21
        620            2006      2328.545
        620            2007      2361.548
        620            2008      3329.636
        620            2009      3069.279
        620            2010      3098.615
        620            2011      2823.59
        620            2012      3373.64
        620            2013      2948.268
```

That is, for the country 886 I don't have values for earlier than 2002.

Now, I'd like to create a CSV with this list, which should list the values for each country in a row, one year after the next - like a table. Which means that if there are no values for certain years, there should be a blank space (or 'null'), as can be seen here:

```
          1990  1991   1992     1993      1994      1995     1996    1997     1998    1999    2000     2001     2002    2003    2004     2005    2006     2007     2008     2009     2010     2011     2012    2013
     620 40.337 1056.096 1151.438 1389.793 1584.144 1631.815 1749.159 1796.83 1906.84 1664.818 1642.816 2016.85 1760.16 1873.837 1961.845 2310.21 2328.545 2361.548 3329.636 3069.279 3098.615 2823.59 3373.64 2948.268
     886                                                                                                        161.348 161.348 176.016 176.016 179.683  183.35   201.685  227.354  234.688  245.689  293.36   440.04
```

Now, I don't succeed in writing a loop, which would take care of those void 'values'. At least not a smooth one. I could retrieve all available years, and then either launch a query for each year and country. Or build a three dimensional array with the results, and use that one for looping. But that looks like weird programming.

I would appreciate any comment on how this can be achieved with a few clean lines of PHP.

Comment: well, you could SELECT all DISTINCT years you have available, combined with all country_id's you have - so you have all combinations of country x year, even if no data is available - and then you just LEFT JOIN your data on those.

Comment: Oh, that sounds promising. Although I played quite a bit around, I did not succeed. Could you scribble down in SQL terms, what you have in mind? How would I 'combine' the DISTINCT(years) with all country_ids? And how to add the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Gleichmann: I am still eager to know how that would work. I uploaded an SQL file with the two tables [here](http://ig3is.grid.unep.ch/temp/test_years_2.sql). It would be great if you could give me an example how the query must look like.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over the min and max of the years found while also looping (inner) over all the companies found will let you create the csv rows without missing any years nor companies:

```
$company_ids = array();
$company_data = array();
$year_min = $year_max = 2016;

$year_fld = 'year_start';
$comp_fld = 'id_country';
$data_fld = 'value_ori';

foreach ($data as &$d) {
  $company_ids[$d[$comp_fld]] = $d[$comp_fld];
  $d[$year_fld] = (integer) $d[$year_fld];
  if ($year_min > $d[$year_fld]) $year_min = $d[$year_fld];
  if ($year_max < $d[$year_fld]) $year_max = $d[$year_fld];
  $company_data[$d[$year_fld]][$d[$comp_fld]] = $d[$data_fld];
}

//die("$year_min $year_max");

//ksort($company_data);
//die('<pre>'.print_r($company_data,true));

$csv_rows = array();
for ($year=$year_min; $year<$year_max+1; $year++) {
  // print rows or accumulate them, whatever
  foreach ($company_ids as &$cid) {
    $csv_rows[$year][$cid] = (empty($company_data[$year][$cid])) ? '' : $company_data[$year][$cid];
  }
}

die('<pre>'.print_r($csv_rows,true));
```

Comment: i did it in two separate looping blocks to clarify things, but if you have a distinct list of countries and know your min/max years already, you should optimize this to not loop over the data entirely before beginning your output as it is more memory intensive and could fail with a very large data set.  hopefully this gets you started, though.